# Windows container

Tags: switch-statement, containers, virtual

I have created Azure VM with Windows server 2016 TP5.

On this server i am able to create images containers and docker engine installation.

My issue as follows

First time everything working proper. But I shutdown VM through azure portal and next day started from portal, I am not able to start any container created on that VM error is as belwo

PS C:> docker start iisdemo
Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint iisdemo on network nat: HNS failed with error : Failed to create e
ndpoint
Error: failed to start containers: iisdemo

Virtual switch details as below .

Befor stutdown VM, Virtual switch type was Internal (Powershell command à Get-VMSwitch)
Name            SwitchType                         NetAdapterInterfaceDescription

----                 ----------                               ------------------------------

Nat                Internal

After start VM, Virtual switch type was changed to  blank (no switch type assign to VM Switch)
Name          SwitchType                         NetAdapterInterfaceDescription

----                 ----------                               ------------------------------

Nat

Please help me how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue with an Azure TP5 VM.  Rebooting didn't work, removing static mappsings didn't work, but re-deploying to a new Azure host got it working.

It's not a solution, but a workaround, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your question.
When you shutdown a VM with the Azure Portal the virtual Machine will be on deallocated status. This means that you lose your IP settings and get dynamically a new IP adres for the VM.
Here you find more information about [IP addresses in Azure and deployment.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm/#public-ip-addresses.)

Hope this information is helpful for you.

Best Regards,
@Jamesvandenberg